# tomcat is unable to start when it is configured to https

Tags: https, localhost

hi i am testing https with localhost with tomcat

i first went the path  to c:/tomcat7

i typed the command keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore mycert.jks

so i got the file mycert.jks in the c:/tomcat7 folder (i gave password as haihai)

then i did the changes of server.xml as follows

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile=”mycert.jks” keysotrePass="haihai"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

but the tomcat is getting started and shutting down immediately.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that If you change the port number here, you should also change the value specified for the redirectPort attribute on the non-SSL connector. This allows Tomcat to automatically redirect users who attempt to access a page with a security constraint specifying that SSL is required, as required by the Servlet Specification.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) you need to provide the full path to the keystore:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

If you want to use the default java keystore, you don't need to provide the keystore path.